# How can I export a Windows Contact Group to CSV?

Tags: windows-vista, export, contacts, csv, address-book

In Windows Vista I am using Windows Contacts. I have a contact group: `C:\Users\Me\Contacts\club.group`. I want to switch to use a service like MailChimp, ConstantContact, etc., those services can import CSV files. How can I export the Windows Contacts Group as a CSV file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open Windows mail.
- From the *Local* folder select *Sent Items*.
- Make a right click on the last message sent to your group.
- Choose *Properties* and the *Details Tab*.
- Copy with the clipboard the e-mail addresses.
- Open Notepad and paste the clipboard.
- From *Edit* menu, replace the `<>`, remove the blank space.
- The file should have one e-mail address for each row. Save the file as `.csv`.
- From Windows Mail choose *File > Import* select your `.csv` File.